# efficient design for database with multiple many to many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm pretty much building my first SQL database and am not sure if I'm going about things in an efficient manner. My data has the following structure: I have a bunch of images, from each of which I extract multiple features. A feature consists of a vector containing one or more floating point numbers. So I have images, features, vector indices, and data values.

My current thinking is to have a single table consisting of {image_id, feature_id, vector_index, data_value}. I guess the primary key would be {image_id, feature_id, vector_index}.

It seems to me that I have multiple many to many relationships, i.e. multiple indices can correspond to a single feature and multiple features can correspond to a single index, multiple images can correspond to the same feature and multiple features can correspond to the same image, etc. From my internet searching it seems like I should be making link tables to make things more efficient, but I can't figure out how that would be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

**To recap**: I have `data_values`, which are floats. Each data value has attributes `image_id`, `feature_id`, and `vector_index`. The tuple {`image_id`, `feature_id`, `vector_index`} uniquely identifies an individual `data_value`.

**There are many-to-many relationships between any pair of attributes:** `image_id`:`feature_id`, `image_id`:`vector_index`, and `vector_index`:`feature_id`.

**Typical query**: Retrieve all data values corresponding to a subset of `image_id`s and `feature_id`s. I will likely never filter based on `vector_index`. For my application I will need the get the queried `data_value`s into a 2D matrix where each row corresponds to a particular `image_id`, and each column corresponds to a particular {`feature_id`, `vector_index`} tuple.

**Current plan**: Get rid of `vector_index`. Instead turn each feature vector into a single string using, e.g., JSON. Construct a database with the following tables:

```
images: {image_id (PK), image_name}  
features: {feature_id (PK), feature_name}  
data_values: {data_id (PK), image_id (FK), feature_id (FK), data_vector}
```

Comment: One thing to consider is exploring the applicability of [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) to this problem as it has native array and JSON data types for storing structured data in a single column. This can often massively simplify your schema.

Answer (score 1):

have a table `image` and a table `feature` and to join them a table `image_feature` that has  two columns, one being the primary key of image the other being the primary key of feature.

Comment: Why would you only make a link table for `image` and `feature` and leave out `vector_index`? It seems to me that qualitatively they are all the same. Also, where would the `data_values` go?

Comment: what is a vector index? what is a data value how do they relate to images and features?

Comment: A feature provides some quantitative description of the content within an image. Each feature is a vector composed of one or more floating point numbers. A data value is one of those floating point numbers. A vector index is an integer specifying the location of a data value within a feature vector.

Comment: For example, suppose I have a grayscale picture of the moon, moon.jpg (an image). I could calculate the center-of-mass of the gray values in this picture (a feature). This would yield a 2-component vector COM = [com_x, com_y] (the data values). In order to ensure that correct ordering of the data values is maintained I assign each an integer denoting its position within the vector e.g. com_x_index = 1, com_y_index = 2 (the vector indices). Therefore each data value can be uniquely identified by its {image, feature, vector index} tuple.

Comment: decomposing the the vector to such an extent seems counter-productive, it smells like `EAV`, I would look for a way to put the whole vector in a single row.

Comment: I could definitely stringify of pickle each vector and store it as a single object, but from my reading I got the impression that this was bad form. Also, (after learning what EAV means) it seems that it's something I'm already using in my generic `features` column that stores the specific feature attribute of each data value. Is this wrong? The only alternative I can see is to use a new column for each feature, which could result in 100s of columns and the need to insert new columns whenever I design a new feature.

Comment: it depends what querties you want to make against this data, for instance if you wanted to be able to find all features in a certain regioin of a certain image having X and Y in disparate columns or on different rows would be bad, but if that's not the sort of thing you want to ask the database to do for you  then it's less important.  if you have features that don't have a location on the image (eg: dominant colour) then this becomes more complicated.

Comment: Typical query would be: retrieve data values corresponding to a subset of images and a subset of features. I will probably always want to retrieve all vector indices for any feature I choose to retreive. The form I will eventually want the data in is a 2D matrix where each row corresponds to data values for a particular image and each column corresponds to data values for a particular {feature_id, vector_index} tuple.